# oracle how to write in stored procedure to get specific values

Tags: oracle, if-statement, switch-statement

I am not sure how to write in stored procedure of Oracle. It is kind of new to me.

```
Table 1:  Bank:

Bank_Id    Description
001        FNB
002        ABSA

Table 2:  Config

Config    ConfigName
1         SUTS allocated
2         SUTS unallocated
3         GOV allocated
4         GOV unallocated

Table 3: Config_Value

Config_Value_Id      Bank_Id    Config_Item_Id  ConfigValue
1                    001         1              FNBSAD
2                    001         2              FNBSUAD
3                    001         3              FNBGAD
4                    001         4              FNBGUAD
```

Config_Value is a relationship between Config and Bank table.

When I write code in C# to set two values of :

- string bank = "FNB"
- string paymentType = "SUTS"

Then these values will pass to stored procedure. I want to write IF or SWITCH statement in stored procedure such as:

```
IF (@PaymentType == 'SUTS')
need to get two values:
  ConfigValue = @param1 where ConfigName = 'SUTS allocated' AND where bank = @bank
  ConfigValue = @param2 where ConfigName = 'SUTS unallocated' AND where bank = @bank

IF (@PaymentType == 'GOV')
need to get two values:
  ConfigValue = @param1 where ConfigName = 'GOVallocated' AND where bank = @bank
  ConfigValue = @param2 where ConfigName = 'GOV unallocated' AND where bank = @bank
```

Once the values (bank and paymentType) passed to stored procedure, fetching two values of ConfigValue based on bank and paymentType. How to write in stored procedure like above? Can you please give me example code? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE Bank
(
    Bank_Id     VARCHAR2(30)
,   Description VARCHAR2(30)
);

INSERT INTO Bank VALUES('001', 'FNB');
INSERT INTO Bank VALUES('002', 'ABSA');

CREATE TABLE Config
(
    Config      NUMBER
,   ConfigName  VARCHAR2(30)
);

INSERT INTO Config VALUES(1, 'SUTS allocated');
INSERT INTO Config VALUES(2, 'SUTS unallocated');
INSERT INTO Config VALUES(3, 'GOV allocated');
INSERT INTO Config VALUES(4, 'GOV unallocated');

CREATE TABLE Config_Value
(
    Config_Value_Id NUMBER
,   Bank_Id         VARCHAR2(30)
,   Config_Item_Id  NUMBER
,   ConfigValue     VARCHAR2(30)
);

INSERT INTO Config_Value VALUES(1, '001', 1, 'FNBSAD');
INSERT INTO Config_Value VALUES(2, '001', 2, 'FNBSUAD');
INSERT INTO Config_Value VALUES(3, '001', 3, 'FNBGAD');
INSERT INTO Config_Value VALUES(4, '001', 4, 'FNBGUAD');

SELECT * FROM Bank;
1   FNB
2   ABSA

SELECT * FROM Config;
1   SUTS allocated
2   SUTS unallocated
3   GOV allocated
4   GOV unallocated

SELECT * FROM Config_Value;
1   001 1   FNBSAD
2   001 2   FNBSUAD
3   001 3   FNBGAD
4   001 4   FNBGUAD

SELECT  *
FROM    Bank         b
JOIN    Config_Value cv ON b.Bank_Id         = cv.Bank_Id
JOIN    Config       c  ON cv.Config_Item_Id = c.Config
;

SELECT  cv.ConfigValue
FROM    Bank         b
JOIN    Config_Value cv ON b.Bank_Id         = cv.Bank_Id
JOIN    Config       c  ON cv.Config_Item_Id = c.Config
WHERE   ConfigName IN ('SUTS allocated', 'SUTS unallocated')
;

SELECT  cv.ConfigValue
FROM    Bank         b
JOIN    Config_Value cv ON b.Bank_Id         = cv.Bank_Id
JOIN    Config       c  ON cv.Config_Item_Id = c.Config
WHERE   ConfigName IN ('GOV allocated', 'GOV unallocated')
;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION c_sharp_function(bank_in IN VARCHAR2, paymentType_in 
VARCHAR2)
RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
    TYPE ConfigValue_ntt IS TABLE OF Config_Value.ConfigValue%TYPE;
    l_ConfigValue  ConfigValue_ntt;
    l_csv          VARCHAR(32767) := '';
BEGIN
    IF UPPER(paymentType_in) LIKE 'SUTS%' THEN
        SELECT  cv.ConfigValue
        BULK    COLLECT INTO l_ConfigValue
        FROM    Bank         b
        JOIN    Config_Value cv ON b.Bank_Id         = cv.Bank_Id
        JOIN    Config       c  ON cv.Config_Item_Id = c.Config
        WHERE   ConfigName IN ('SUTS allocated', 'SUTS unallocated')
        AND     Description  = bank_in;
    ELSIF UPPER(paymentType_in) LIKE 'GOV%' THEN
        SELECT  cv.ConfigValue
        BULK    COLLECT INTO l_ConfigValue
        FROM    Bank         b
        JOIN    Config_Value cv ON b.Bank_Id         = cv.Bank_Id
        JOIN    Config       c  ON cv.Config_Item_Id = c.Config
        WHERE   ConfigName IN ('GOV allocated', 'GOV unallocated')
        AND     Description  = bank_in;
    END IF;

    FOR indx IN 1..l_ConfigValue.COUNT LOOP
        l_csv := l_csv || l_ConfigValue(indx) || ',';
    END LOOP;

    l_csv := SUBSTR(l_csv, 1, LENGTH(l_csv) - 1);

    RETURN l_csv;
END;

DECLARE
    l_get_csv VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
    l_get_csv := c_sharp_function('FNB', 'SUTS');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_get_csv);

    l_get_csv := c_sharp_function('ABSA', 'GOV');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_get_csv);
END;
/*
FNBSAD,FNBSUAD

FNBSAD,FNBSUAD
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

A procedure to do this would require two input parameters (`PaymentType` and `bank`) and two output parameters (`param1` and `param2`).

Note that Oracle parameters, unlike SQL Server and MySQL, are set off with a colon (`:`) rather than an "at" sign (`@`), so in your C# code you'll need to name them `:PaymentType`, `:bank`, `:param1`, and `:param2`.

Also note that when you write the C# code you must name the parameters *exactly* as they're named in Oracle (except for the colon in front). If you don't, the C# code will compile fine but it will fail at runtime. If your first parameter is `PaymentType` in Oracle, it should be called `:PaymentType` in C#.

One more note: I'm not sure how your `Config` and `Config_Value` tables are related. Based on the test data, it could be through `Config_Value.Config_Value_Id` or `Config_Value.Config_Item_Id`. I went with `Config_Item_Id`.

The Oracle procedure would go something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE myProc(
   PaymentType VARCHAR,
   bank VARCHAR,
   param1 OUT VARCHAR,
   param2 OUT VARCHAR)
AS
BEGIN
  IF PaymentType = 'SUTS' THEN
    SELECT ConfigValue INTO param1
      FROM Config_Value
      INNER JOIN Bank ON Config_Value.Bank_ID = Bank.Bank_ID
      INNER JOIN Config ON Config_Value.Config_Item_Id = Config.Config
      WHERE Bank.Description = bank
        AND Config.ConfigName = 'SUTS allocated';
    -- Now for param2; the only difference is the first line (INTO param2)
    -- and the last line (ConfigName = 'SUTS unallocated').
    SELECT ConfigValue INTO param2
      FROM Config_Value
      INNER JOIN Bank ON Config_Value.Bank_ID = Bank.Bank_ID
      INNER JOIN Config ON Config_Value.Config_Item_Id = Config.Config
      WHERE Bank.Description = bank
        AND Config.ConfigName = 'SUTS unallocated';
  ELSE
    -- Do the same as above, but for 'GOV' instead of 'SUTS'.
  END IF;
END myProc;
/
```

If all your options are "payment type" plus "allocated" or "unallocated" you can do away with the "if" logic by just building the "* allocated" and "* unallocated" values:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE myProc(
   PaymentType VARCHAR,
   bank VARCHAR,
   param1 OUT VARCHAR,
   param2 OUT VARCHAR)
AS
BEGIN
  -- param1
  SELECT ConfigValue INTO param1
    FROM Config_Value
    INNER JOIN Bank ON Config_Value.Bank_ID = Bank.Bank_ID
    INNER JOIN Config ON Config_Value.Config_Item_Id = Config.Config
    WHERE Bank.Description = bank
      AND Config.ConfigName = PaymentType || ' allocated';
  -- param2
  SELECT ConfigValue INTO param2
    FROM Config_Value
    INNER JOIN Bank ON Config_Value.Bank_ID = Bank.Bank_ID
    INNER JOIN Config ON Config_Value.Config_Item_Id = Config.Config
    WHERE Bank.Description = bank
      AND Config.ConfigName = PaymentType || ' unallocated';
END;
/
```

I haven't tested this but it should at least be close. I hope it's enough to get you started.

If you get the message "procedure created" then the syntax was OK and it's time to test the proc. If you get the message "procedure created with errors", type `show errors` at the SQLPlus prompt to see a list of the errors.

Comment: Great example! I will test it. Thanks for using your time to explain it. Thanks so much